# Is there any way to Logback and Log4J in parallel?

Tags: log4j, jetty, logback

Is there a possibility to run both Log4J and Logback in parallel on Jetty?
For now it looks like Logback intercepts all the output, is there a way to write Log4J at least to a separate file?

Thanks!